# How to create rolling logger in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to create a rolling logger for an application similar to Linux's automatic rolling logger. The logger should create a directory called `logs` (if it doesn't exist) and create a new log file each time the application is run. I want the program to have a cap of 10 log files named `log0000.log` to `log0010.log`. If there are more than 10 files in the `logs` directory, it deletes the oldest log file and then shifts/rolls/renames all of the files to make room for the current log.

[image]

Since there are more than 10 files, it should delete `log0000.log` and rename each logfile to make room for a new file. I have implemented the creating logs logic each time the program is run but I'm having trouble shifting the logs when there are more than 10 files in the directory.

```
import os
import time
import logging

class RollingLogger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.NUMBER_OF_LOGS = 10
        self.initialize_logger_settings()

    def initialize_logger_settings(self):
        """Set logger configuration settings"""

        self.initialize_log_directory()
        logging.basicConfig(filename= self.path + self.filename, 
                            filemode='w', 
                            level=logging.INFO, 
                            format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d,%(message)s',
                            datefmt='%d-%b-%y,%H:%M:%S')
        logging.info('Successfully loaded logger configuration settings')

    def initialize_log_directory(self):
        """Create directory and log file"""

        self.path = 'logs/'

        if not os.path.exists(self.path):
            os.makedirs(self.path)
            self.filename = 'log0000.log'
        else:
            self.filename = self.get_next_log_file_name()

    def get_next_log_file_name(self):
        """Scans log directory for latest log file and returns a new filename"""

        def extract_digits(filename):
            s = ''
            for char in filename:
                if char.isdigit():
                    s += char
            return int(s)

        l = [extract_digits(filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.path)]
        # Directory is empty
        if not l:
            return 'log0000.log'
        # Directory has files so find latest
        else:
            latest_file_number = max(l)
            return 'log' + '{0:04d}'.format(latest_file_number + 1) + '.log'

logger = RollingLogger()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you should do is this:

- Check if you have reached the maximum file number
- Delete the last file
- Rename the files - 8-->9, 7-->8 and so on
- Create file number 0

Your `else` clause should look like this:

```
else:
    latest_file_number = max(l)
    if latest_file_number >= self.NUMBER_OF_LOGS - 1:
        largest_file_name = self.path + 'log' + '{0:04d}'.format(latest_file_number) + '.log'
        os.remove(largest_file_name)
        for i in range(self.NUMBER_OF_LOGS - 1, 0, -1):
            name1 = self.path + 'log' + '{0:04d}'.format(i - 1) + '.log'
            name2 = self.path + 'log' + '{0:04d}'.format(i) + '.log'
            os.rename(name1, name2)
        return 'log0000.log'
    return 'log' + '{0:04d}'.format(latest_file_number + 1) + '.log'
```

Also note that if you want to have 10 files, their numbers will be in the range 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

1 create an logger.ini file

```
[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = rotatingFileHandler,streamHandler,errorHandler

[formatters]
keys = simpleFmt

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = rotatingFileHandler,streamHandler,errorHandler

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level = INFO
formatter = simpleFmt
args = (os.path.abspath(os.getenv("LOG_PATH") + "/default.log"),"midnight", 1, 6,'utf-8')


[handler_errorHandler]
class = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level = ERROR
formatter = simpleFmt
args = (os.path.abspath(os.getenv("LOG_PATH") + "/error.log"), "midnight", 1, 6,'utf-8')

[handler_streamHandler]
level = INFO
class = StreamHandler
formatter = simpleFmt
args = (sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFmt]
format = %(asctime)s %(pathname)s(%(lineno)d): %(levelname)s %(message)s
```

2  use the ini file to init in my_logger.py

```
def get_logger(name='root'):
    import logging.config
    import os
    conf_log = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + "/logger.ini")
    logging.config.fileConfig(conf_log)
    return logging.getLogger(name)


LOGGER = get_logger()
```

3 set log_path

```
os.environ["LOG_PATH"] = "d:/tmp/log/viot"
```

4 use LOGGER  to log

```
from my_logger import LOGGER 
LOGGER.debug("log msg")
```